# how can I run Rack::Static only if it starting in production env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, development-environment, environment-variables

I have a config.ru for Rails 3.0.5 app like this :

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/uploads'], :root => 'tmp'

run newapp::Application
```

but I want to exec the `use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/uploads'], :root => 'tmp'` line if and only if Rails start in production.

How can I do it ?
Thanks in advance 
luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this in your config.ru you can do it in your environment, so in `production.rb` add this:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/uploads'], :root => 'tmp'
```